# Django Ajax will not post a file (online site available for running the sample)

Tags: ajax, django

The website and place of doubt is online, link below. I have cloned a git site and just added one File Field to the Models.py and to the Forms.py but, as you can test, it will refuse to accept that a file has been uploaded and will not post the form because it says the field is missing the file.

```
https://mysite-mayarodina.c9users.io/books/
```

The files in question>

models

from **future** import unicode_literals

from django.db import models

```
class Book(models.Model):
    HARDCOVER = 1
    PAPERBACK = 2
    EBOOK = 3
    BOOK_TYPES = (
        (HARDCOVER, 'Hardcover'),
        (PAPERBACK, 'Paperback'),
        (EBOOK, 'E-book'),
    )
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    publication_date = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    author = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2)
    pages = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    book_type = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(choices=BOOK_TYPES,    blank=True, null=True)
    book = models.FileField("none.jpg")
```

the jquery that executes the code

```
$(function () {

  /* Functions */

  var loadForm = function () {
    var btn = $(this);
    $.ajax({
      url: btn.attr("data-url"),
      type: 'get',
      dataType: 'json',
      beforeSend: function () {
        $("#modal-book .modal-content").html("");
        $("#modal-book").modal("show");
      },
      success: function (data) {
        $("#modal-book .modal-content").html(data.html_form);
      }
    });
  };

  var saveForm = function () {
    var form = $(this);
    $.ajax({
      url: form.attr("action"),
      data: form.serialize(),
      type: form.attr("method"),
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function (data) {
        if (data.form_is_valid) {
          $("#book-table tbody").html(data.html_book_list);
          $("#modal-book").modal("hide");
        }
        else {
          $("#modal-book .modal-content").html(data.html_form);
        }
      }
    });
    return false;
  };


  /* Binding */

  // Create book
  $(".js-create-book").click(loadForm);
  $("#modal-book").on("submit", ".js-book-create-form", saveForm);

  // Update book
  $("#book-table").on("click", ".js-update-book", loadForm);
  $("#modal-book").on("submit", ".js-book-update-form", saveForm);

  // Delete book
  $("#book-table").on("click", ".js-delete-book", loadForm);
  $("#modal-book").on("submit", ".js-book-delete-form", saveForm);

});
```

The views:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from django.http import JsonResponse
from django.template.loader import render_to_string

from .models import Book
from .forms import BookForm


def book_list(request):
    books = Book.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'books/book_list.html', {'books': books})


def save_book_form(request, form, template_name):
    data = dict()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            data['form_is_valid'] = True
            books = Book.objects.all()
            data['html_book_list'] = render_to_string('books/includes/partial_book_list.html', {
                'books': books
            })
        else:
            data['form_is_valid'] = False
    context = {'form': form}
    data['html_form'] = render_to_string(template_name, context, request=request)
    return JsonResponse(data)


def book_create(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = BookForm(request.POST)
    else:
        form = BookForm()
    return save_book_form(request, form, 'books/includes/partial_book_create.html')
```

The partial that contains the form

```
 <form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="{% url 'book_create' %}" class="js-book-create-form">
  {% csrf_token %}
  <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
      <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
    </button>
    <h4 class="modal-title">Create a new book</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    {% include 'books/includes/partial_book_form.html' %}
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Create book</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: You can't send a file like that with Ajax.

Comment: why not? that is the key thing to know. and the second thing, is, what to do then? I am aware of the following, but it seems that was true back in 2010. Today browsers support it " ..A file cannot be uploaded using AJAX because you cannot access the contents of a file stored on the client computer and send it in the request using javascript. One of the techniques to achieve this is to use hidden iframes ..".

Comment: Because all you do is serialize the form inputs and post them. That won't do anything with the file at all. Yes, modern browsers do indeed support sending files by Ajax, but for that you need to use a FormData object.

Comment: Thank you. I will research what that is. At least now I know why. Now I can take it from her. Best regards.  I remember you helped me brightly in my other account.